# How to display the menu name of a menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a menu with the name **"alggemeen"** and added some items to it.

[image]

I have assigned the menu to the theme location Footer menu with the slug **'footer-menu'**.

[image]

Now I know how to display the content of menu and also the menu_location. But I want to display the name the wordpress admin will provide in backend for the menu, on my website.

I would like to echo the name of the menu that has been allocated to the menu with a theme location of `'Footer Menu(slug = 'footer-menu')'`.

So as shown above in the picture Currently alggemeen is the menu assigned to Footer Menu so my front end should echo algemeen.

Comment: May be this shall help you : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-menu-name-in-a-given-location

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$menu_location = 'header';

$menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

$menu_object = (isset($menu_locations[$menu_location]) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_locations[$menu_location]) : null);

$menu_name = (isset($menu_object->name) ? $menu_object->name : '');

echo esc_html($menu_name);
```